# Passing JSON data to .getJSON in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, jsonp, getjson

I am trying to pass a JSON object to .getJSON but I keep getting a bad request error. This is what I am trying:

```
var data = {
    "SomeID": "18",
    "Utc": null,
    "Flags": "324"
};

$.getJSON("https://somewhere.com/AllGet?callback=?", JSON.stringify(data), function (result) {
    alert(result);
});
```

Currently to get it working, I have to do this, but I do not like how I have to manually construct the query string:

```
$.getJSON("https://somewhere.com/AllGet?SomeID=18&Utc=&Flags=324&callback=?", null, function (result) {
        alert(result);
    });
```

Anyone know how to make requests easier with JSON objects being passed in? I would appreciate any help or advise.

Comment: try `$.param(data);` it outputs `"SomeID=18&Utc=null&Flags=324"`

Answer (score 31, accepted):

according to the site, this is valid:

```
$.getJSON("test.js", { name: "John", time: "2pm" }, function(json) {
    alert("JSON Data: " + json.users[3].name);
    });
```

so try:

```
var data = {
    SomeID: "18",
    Utc: null,
    Flags: "324"
};

$.getJSON("https://somewhere.com/AllGet?callback=?", data, function (result) {
    alert(result);
});
```

edit: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/

Answer (score 3):

Dont use JSON.stringfy, just pass data as it is.

```
$.getJSON("https://somewhere.com/AllGet?callback=?", data, function (result) {
    alert(result);
});
```

Answer (score 3):

When you provide data to a jQuery GET request, it expects an *object*, not a JSON string, for constructing the query string parameters.  Try changing your original code to just this:

```
$.getJSON("https://somewhere.com/AllGet?callback=?", data, function (result) {
    alert(result);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

why exactly do you need a callback? (Ow wait, jsonp) I'd try the following first:

```
$.getJSON("https://somewhere.com/AllGet?callback=?", data, function(result) {
  alert(result);
});
```

somewhere in firebug and see if it returns what you expect. I'm not sure what a string as data does, but just giving an object works fine afaik.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to do `JSON.stringfy`, just pass the **JSON** object, jQuery will construct your URL parameter with that

```
$.getJSON("https://somewhere.com/AllGet?callback=?", data, function (result) {
    alert(result);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$.getJSON("https://somewhere.com/AllGet?callback=?", {SomeID:"18",Utc:null,Flags:"324"}, function (result) {
        alert(result);
    });
```

OR

```
var data = {
    "SomeID": "18",
    "Utc": null,
    "Flags": "324"
};


$.getJSON("https://somewhere.com/AllGet?callback=?",
 {
SomeID:data.SomeID,
Utc:data.Utc,
Flags:data.Flags
},
 function (result) {
            alert(result);
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried encoding the json and it worked.

Not sure how efficient or practical it is, sharing it just as a work around for above question.

```
 $.getJSON("https://somewhere.com/AllGet?data="+encodeURI(JSON.stringify(data)), function (result) {
        alert(result);
 });
```