# Sending complex Javascript variable as JSON returns 400 bad

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, json, json.net

I have the following setup

On client side I am using a complex Javascript variable something like this

```
var order = {
             name:"",
             id:"",
             cost:"",
             details:{
                      sItem:[{name:"",cost:""}], 
                      dItem:[{name:"",cost:"", components:[{name:"",quantity:""}]}]
                     }
            }
```

I have a controller on server in c# like this

```
    public string getCost(string order)
    {
        var sOrder = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(order);
//do the processing here
        return "I am processed";
    }
```

In my Javascript I am calling this as

```
$.getJSON("Api/menu/getCost/" +  JSON.stringify(order),
                function (data) {
                    window.alert('i m here : success');
                });
```

The problem is when I send this request the server responds with bad request, however if I append a simple string like "hello" instead of JSON.stringify(order). The controller receives it and returns with success with no problem, so I know the problem is somewhere in converting the order to JSON but dont know how to find out.

Yes, I am using getJSON and returning a simple string but thats not a problem, as I will be returning a JSON string later on when the processing is done. Actually that will be the same JSON received with some values of the properties changed.

Comment: Don't you want to send the id instead of the full json ? You can't send json through URL, some characters might not be supported

Comment: In some cases there is no Id for the items inside the nested structure and therefore I need to send all the order object. Furthermore it will make it easy on both the server and client side if they just have a common object to deal with, partly filled by client and partly filled by the server.

Comment: Well I've got confused by DeserializeObject<dynamic>(id); which was supposing an ID. If you absolutely need to send the data, do a POST request instead of passing into URL.

Comment: oh yes, I have corrected it. 
Do you mean calling a postJSON instead of getJSON? Or something else

Comment: I hope the below stackoverflow post can help you. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8232197/passing-json-data-to-getjson-in-jquery

Comment: note that you are not going to get a json return. you are going to get jqXHR.

Comment: @Winter How do we get the data inside the controller then?

Answer (score 0):

I played with $.get, $.post, $.getJSON, etc.  While I got some of them to work, they always returned jqXHR even though the response was a serialized JSON object.
Below is the only way I have been successful.  (Note that I am hitting a web service.)

```
       <script type="text/javascript">

        $(document).ready(function () {

            $.ajax({
                url: "WebService1.asmx/GetAList",
             //   data: JSON.stringify({ s: parms }),
                type: 'post',
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (data, status) {
                    var contries = JSON.parse(data.d);
                    $("#sel2").select2({ data: contries });
                },
                error: function (one, two) {
                    debugger;
                }
            });
        });
            </script>


        </head>
        <body>
            <form>
                <div>
                    <p>populated from ajax</p>
                    <select style="width:175px" id="sel2"></select>
                </div>
            </form>
        </body>
</html>
```

and my web service

using System.Web.Script.Services;

```
    namespace WebApplication1
    {    // a class in context with how the data are is being used
        [Serializable]
        public class select2Item
        {
            public String id { get; set; }
            public String text { get; set; }
            public select2Item(String code, String name)
            {
                this.id = code;
                this.text = name;
            }
            public select2Item() { }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Summary description for WebService1
        /// </summary>
        [WebService(Namespace = "http://tempuri.org/")]
        [WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
        [System.ComponentModel.ToolboxItem(false)]
        [System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService]
        public class WebService1 : System.Web.Services.WebService
        {


            [WebMethod]
            public string GetAList()
            {
                System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer ser = new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer();
                return makelist();
            }

             // return a list of serialized codes and countries
            public String makelist()
            {
                List<select2Item> list = new List<select2Item>();

                list.Add(new select2Item("AI", "Anguilla"));
                list.Add(new select2Item("AQ", "Antarctica"));
                list.Add(new select2Item("AG", "Antigua and Barbuda"));
                list.Add(new select2Item("AR", "Argentina"));
                list.Add(new select2Item("AM", "Armenia"));
                list.Add(new select2Item("AW", "Aruba"));
                list.Add(new select2Item("AU", "Australia"));
                list.Add(new select2Item("AT", "Austria"));
                list.Add(new select2Item("AZ", "Azerbaijan"));
                list.Add(new select2Item("BS", "Bahamas"));
                list.Add(new select2Item("BH", "Bahrain"));
                list.Add(new select2Item("BD", "Bangladesh"));
                list.Add(new select2Item("BB", "Barbados"));
                list.Add(new select2Item("BY", "Belarus"));
                list.Add(new select2Item("BE", "Belgium"));
                list.Add(new select2Item("BZ", "Belize"));
                // did it this way to show you which to use
                System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer ser = new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer();
                String jsonList = ser.Serialize(list);
                return jsonList;
            }
         }
    }
```