# how to change the code from $.ajax() to $.getJSON

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax

this code works using ajax and I want to change it using json, what is the right way to use it?

AJAX

```
$('#movie-list').on('click', '.see-detail', function() {
$.ajax({
    url: 'http://omdbapi.com',
    dataType: 'json',
    data: {
        'apikey' : 'myapikey',
        'i' : $(this).data('id')
    },
    success: function (movie) {
        $('.modal-body').html(`...`);
    }
})
});
```

JSON

```
$('#movie-list').on('click', '.see-detail', function() {
$.getJSON('http://www.omdbapi.com/?apikey=myapikey&i=='+ $(this).data('id') +'', function(data) {
    $('.modal-body').html(`...`);
});
});
```

Comment: both are ajax, what is your problem ? maybe  `=` instead of `==` ?

Comment: AJAX and JSON are two different things and are not interchangeable, JSON is the format through which data is communicated over the network, where AJAX is the process which helps fetching data to/from the network. So, you have to be more clear, what actually you are looking for.

Comment: @HamzaArshad — Err. They aren't asking about JSON, they are asking about the `getJSON` method.

Comment: @mpromonet it doesn't work, I've tried it

Comment: Pass the data as second arguement. 
Following answer might be helpful:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8232197/passing-json-data-to-getjson-in-jquery

Comment: It appears that you have posted sensitive/private information. Please reset your passwords and/or revoke API keys and tokens, as they are considered compromised when posted on the internet. If personally-identifiable information was posted, please [edit] out the info then flag your post for a moderator to redact the revisions.

Comment: Minus the `==` typo, your code works fine.  https://jsfiddle.net/6dqn5w34/1/  (put your private key instead of xxxxx)

Comment: @freedomn-m thanks, this 100%works

Answer (score 0):

Look at [the documentation](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/):

> ```
> jQuery.getJSON( url [, data ] [, success ] )
> ```

So:

```
jQuery.getJSON(
    'http://omdbapi.com',           // url
    {                               // data
        'apikey' : 'myapikey',
        'i' : $(this).data('id')
    },
    function (movie) {              // success
        $('.modal-body').html(`...`);
    }
);
```

---

While you *could* munge the query string on to the URL by mashing strings together: **Don't**. We use libraries to do it because they are less error prone and know all the rules for properly escaping data.